# How to access to d in this clisp list?

Tags: clisp

I have this clisp list and would like to access the atom d in 
    (a (b c . d))
With 
    (set 'list '(a (b c . d)))
    (car (cdr (car (cdr list))))  or (car (cdr (car (cdr '(a (b c . d))))))
I get c, I really don't know how to do to get d

```
Thank you for all!
```

Kwatford got me this answer
    (set 'list '(a (b c . d)))
    (a (b c . d))
    (cddadr list)
    d

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this one step at a time...

```
* (set 'list '(a (b c . d)))

(A (B C . D))
```

The CAR of this list is A. We want something in its CDR instead.

```
* (cdr list)

((B C . D))
```

This is a list of one element. Its CAR is the inner list, and CDR is nil.

```
* (car (cdr list))

(B C . D)
```

Now we get to the weird looking part. Don't worry too much about it - we know that its CAR is B, and we don't want that, so it must be in the CDR...

```
* (cdr (car (cdr list)))

(C . D)
```

This is the final CONS cell. The CAR is C, but what about the CDR?

```
* (cdr (cdr (car (cdr list))))

D
```

Okay, that worked, but what's up with that little dot? Normally the contents of the CDR of a list is another CONS cell. Lists are implemented as a linked list, with each cell containing an element in the CAR and a pointer to the next list node in the CDR. But that's only true for lists - there's no rule that a CONS cell has to contain an item and then another list. The dot is how the interpreter lets you know that this isn't quite a list, and the CDR isn't a CONS.

Anyway, here's the short way to get your D:

```
* (cddadr list)

D
```